# How to change suexec root directory from "/var/www" to "/home"?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, suexec

Hi I've installed suexec using on ubuntu 12.04:

```
apt-get install apache2 apache2-suexec libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
```

However when I run the following command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
```

I get the following info:

```
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="www-data"
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache2/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=100
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

I'm utilizing "/home/user/public_html" to serve users content on the web not "/var/www" 
How can I change the root directory to "/home"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using ubuntu. Therefore recompile is pretty simple.

Add source repository to your /etc/apt/sources.list . For 12.04 run

```
echo "deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main"|sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

change `de.archive.ubuntu.com` to whatever country you're in. After that update your repository.

```
apt-get update
```

Change dir and download sources:

```
mkdir ~/apache_new  ; cd ~/apache_new
apt-get source apache2
apt-get build-dep apache2
```

It will download and extract apache source and install all dependencies therefore you'll be able to build apache.
But you'll need to fix AP_DOC_ROOT. So cd to dir with apache source and change dir path in `--with-suexec-docroot` option in `debian/rules` file.
So now you'll need to build package. You can make it with

```
debuild -us -uc
```

That's it. Now yyou have apache deb-package with fixed path. Just install it with `sudo dpkg -i`.
But watch on updates. Update will wipe out all your efforts. So run `aptitude hold apache2` to forbid updates and don't forget to recompile it each time manually (or write script fpr that).

Good luck.

Answer (score 16):

Or you can

```
apt-get install apache2-suexec-custom
```

after install go to

```
cd /etc/apache2/suexec
```

edit the file
    vi www-data

You can see the first 2 lines, make the changes: replace `/var/www` with `/home`

```
esc 
:wq
```

after, restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Make sure to also **remove** apache2-suexec and apache2-suexec-pristine or this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm utilizing "/home/user/public_html" to serve users content on the
>   web not "/var/www" How can I change the root directory to "/home"?

actually you can use mod_userdir

in this case suexec will spawn scripts from owner of /home/user  - in this example "user"

so you don't need to define SuexecUserGroup in apache config

UPD:
just enable userdir module

and add to main vhost config

UserDir /home/*/public_html

and

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/ >
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl  .py .rb
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile it from suexec.c, ideally you could install virtualmin, so it will do it automatically via install.sh and also it will create accounts, domains etc.