# Multiple VHosts with FastCGI and Suexec

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, fastcgi, suexec

I have a Debian virtual machine server which I have full control over, but I have someone who wants to host a single domain on it. This is obviously a security concern, as even if his particular user cannot read all of the other domain's files, any script he runs (PHP) on the webserver can. To illustrate:

```
% ls -l /srv
drwxr-x--x 5 admin    admin    4096 Mar  4 13:29 secretsite.com
drwxr-x--x 4 bob      bob      4096 Apr  4 12:41 mycoolsite.co.uk
$ su - bob
$ ls /srv/
ls: cannot open directory /srv/: Permission denied
$ ls -R /srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/
/srv/mycoolsite.co.uk:
public

/srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/public:
htdocs

/srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/public/htdocs:
index.php
```

However:

```
$ cat /srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/public/htdocs

<?php
echo shell_exec('whoami');

echo shell_exec('ls /srv');
?>
```

Which outputs in a browser: `www-data  secretsite.com mycoolsite.co.uk`... not very desirable.

So I decided to use FastCGI and Suexec to make sure bob's PHP files were executed as him. I was mostly following the instructions given [here](http://x10hosting.com/forums/vps-tutorials/148894-debian-apache-2-2-fastcgi-php-5-suexec-easy-way.html), but I already have a mass-hosting Apache configuration all set up.

In `sites-enabled` I have this configuration file called `zz-mass-hosting`:

```
NameVirtualHost my.ip.address:80

<VirtualHost my.ip.address:80>
    <Directory "/srv">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    UseCanonicalName        Off

    VirtualDocumentRoot     /srv/%0/public/htdocs/
    VirtualScriptAlias      /srv/%0/public/cgi-bin/

    SetVirtualDocumentRoot on


</VirtualHost>
```

Which works great.

So, for setting up this domain, `mycoolsite.co.uk`, specifically I installed through apt: `libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec-custom php5-cgi`

I modified `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data` to read: `/srv`. With no second line. And created `/etc/apache2/conf.d/php5-fastcgid.conf`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

AddHandler php-fcgi .php
Action php-fcgi /fcgi-bin/php5-fcgi

Alias /fcgi-bin/ /home/www-data/

<Location /fcgi-bin/>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

/home/www-data/php5-fcgi is:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

with ownership `www-data:www-data`. I created `/home/www-data/bob` with ownership `bob:bob` and copied `php5-fcgi` there.

I then created `zzz-mycoolsite.co.uk` in `sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost my.ip.address:80>

             ServerAdmin admin@mycoolsite.co.uk
             ServerName mycoolsite.co.uk

             Alias /fcgi-bin/ /home/www-data/bob/
             SuexecUserGroup bob bob

             DocumentRoot /srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/public/htdocs/

             <Directory /srv/mycoolsite.co.uk/public/htdocs/>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride None
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
             </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I activate this site, and go to `mycoolsite.co.uk/index.php` it still says it is running as `www-data`. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably ut's because by default the suexec root from debian is compiled with /var/www and you are trying to use of at /srv.
See also: [How to change suexec root directory from "/var/www" to "/home"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/402418/how-to-change-suexec-root-directory-from-var-www-to-home)

Comment: I thought `apache2-suexec-custom` was meant to solve that. "I modified /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data to read: /srv"